# Does MongoDB support aggregate queries on the result of the aggregate query?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation

I have an aggregate query that returns the count of records a property has.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $group : {
            _id : "$propertyId",
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort : { count: 1 }
    }
],
{
    allowDiskUse:true
});
```

This gives me a result that looks like this.

```
{ "_id" : 1234, "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 1235, "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 1236, "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : 1237, "count" : 3 }
{ "_id" : 1238, "count" : 3 }
```

Now I want to count the counts. So the above result would turn into this.

```
{ "_id" : 1, "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : 2, "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 3, "count" : 2 }
```

Is this possible to do with a query, or do I need to write some code to get this done?

Comment: This can be done by adding another $group stage the aggregation. The `_id` of that stage would be `$count`.

Answer (score 0):

I updated the query to have another "step" that counts the counts. This is how it looks.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $group : {
            _id : "$propertyId",
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    },
    {
        $group : {
            _id : "$count",
            countOfCounts: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort : { countOfCounts: 1 }
    }
],
{
    allowDiskUse:true
});
```